# Не получается распараллелить метод решения СЛАУ методом Гаусса с OpenMP

Tags: c++, openmp

Функция принимает на вход матрицу, и решает СЛАУ. Но время выполнения без omp и с omp не отличается (т.е если комментировать строку с `#pragma parallel`). В свойствах проекта поддержка openMP включена, если ставлю `num_threads = 1`, то код замедляется (т.е параллельный алгоритм работает). Время при `n = 3000`, 4.5 секунды на обоих алгоритмах, а на параллельном должно быть в 2 раза быстрее. В чем может быть ошибка?

```
void gaussMethod(vector<vector<double>> a, vector<double> b, int n, vector<double> y)
{
    int i, j, k;
    double ratio;
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) 
    {
#pragma omp parallel for private(j,k,ratio) num_threads(12)
        for (j = i+1; j < n; j++) 
        {
            ratio = a[j][i] / a[i][i];
            for (k = i; k <= n; k++) 
                a[j][k] -= ratio * a[i][k];
            b[j] -= ratio * b[i];
        }
    }
    for (int k = n - 1; k >= 0; k--) 
    {
        double d = 0;
        for (int j = k + 1; j < n; j++)
            d += a[k][j] * y[j];
        y[k] = (b[k] - d) / a[k][k];
    }
}
```

Comment: `std::thread` не?

Comment: @megorit нужно через openMP

Comment: Всякие такие штуки больше годятся для распределенных вычислений, т.е. по сети.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается всё дело было в конфигурации. Если запускать в `Release`, то эффекта вроде как и нет. А если в `Debug`, то есть ускорении в разы.